# How to keep the user "www-data" when modify file logged in as root?

Tags: linux, nginx, sftp

I gave permission to the user "www-data" in the entire contents of the "/var/www" folder.

However, I work with the root user with a private key via SFTP, and whenever I modify a file, the owner of the file becomes root.

How to edit the files and keep the "www-data" as owner?

Comment: I do not know the correct answer, but I judge it has something with SUID SGID and sticky bit. You can get more than 100 hits if looking for that keywords.

Comment: @roaima Thanks for the comment, you opened my mind. I really had not thought that when a file is modified it was deleted and a new file was created. So I went to check if the creation date was changed, and found that there is no date of creation of a file on linux systems. What I have to do is change the owner of the file again every time I modify it, so nginx will work normally.

Answer (score 2):

With `sftp` you don't modify a file in place, you copy it to your machine, modify it, and then replace it with the new version, which necessarily then is owned by the user you connected as.  Use other means of editing. 
`sshfs` might be an option; use a sensible editor like `vi` ;) through `ssh`.